# vTiger Contacts - Change Default View

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Is it possible to change the default view when a user selects a Contact from the system to display their info? By default the 'Contact Summary' is displayed whereas I'd like to display the 'Contact Details' as seen when the user clicks on Contact Details from the right side menu. I cannot find where in the system this choice is set...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the default record view user wise but that will be for all modules. Go to My Preference page which you can get by clicking on User name in Top Right corner.

Now on that page find a block "More Information" and set the value of "Default record View" field to Detail so when ever you will open any module record it will get detail view of that record.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can.

- Go to the Admin section
- Studio
- Module manager
- Select Contacts module
- Click on field which you want to appear on Summary page.
- Select "Summary View"

For more details you can refer [vTiger Summary Page info](https://wiki.vtiger.com/vtiger6/index.php/Summary_View)

Comment: To whomever it may concern.... If you are giving down marking then please explain why you are doing this....